# Where to put javascript that you don't always want to load?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using RoR and jquery.ui.addresspicker.js

This jquery.ui.addresspicker.js requires that google is loaded before that library is loaded.  I only need the addresspicker on a couple of pages in the application.

The google part that needs to be loaded before is this:

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

But this makes the page load slower so I don't want this on all my pages.

The application.js contains this:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.ui.all
//= require jquery.blockUI
//= require select2
//= require cocoon

//= require_tree .
```

Currently the jquery.ui.addresspicker.js file is in app/assets/javascripts and thus also loaded automatically all the time.

How can I handle this?  Should I move the addresspicker.js out of the javascripts directory?  Should I rewrite my application.js?  Other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used Ian's idea to change the application.js

I created a new folder named sitewide and copied all the javascripts in there that I want to use on the whole site (so not the addresspicker).

I changed application.js like this:

```
//= require_tree ./sitewide
```

And in the page where I needed the addresspicker I put it using javascript_include_tag

This way I don't need to change the application.js file everytime I want to add a js file.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace

```
//= require_tree .
```

with an explicit list of the javascripts that you want included on each page. and just include `jquery.ui.addresspicker` on the pages that you need it.

Answer (score 0):

use a different layout on both pages or just remove the jquery.ui.addresspicker.js from the default_layout and just include in the pages where you need it

```
<%= include_javascripts "jquery.ui.addresspicker" %> or
javascript_include_tag "jquery.ui.addresspicker"
```

in the page where you need